# Remotely shutting down Windows 7 causes restart using RDC

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, shutdown, reboot

I connect to a desktop machine on my LAN using RDC and use `shutdown.exe -f` to force a shutdown. For some reason, the machine almost always restarts instead. I have also tried `shutdown.exe - s` but with the same result.

The machine in question is running Windows 7 (64 Bit) with all Windows Updates applied.

Am I missing something and is there an alternative way to shut down?

Comment: What happens when you use Windows Security from the Start Menu and choose the Shut Down option there?

Comment: What if open command prompt and type shutdown -s -f -t 10
Where s = shutdown, f = force and t = time and the numbers is seconds (I put this for clarity for everyone to read, I'm sure you know this already)

Comment: Actually I have not tried -s and -f together, although the command prompt documentation for -s clearly states shutdown. Will give this a try and revert back.

Comment: The -i option also seems worth a try.

Comment: It appears that the problem had nothing to do with RDC. The machine in question does the same sometimes when shutdown from the start menu without remoting.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

**shutdown /f /s /t 0**

/f (force)
/s (shutdown)
/t 0 (instantly)

Comment: This should do the trick.  Use f and s.